# What affects the path of the ball after impact?

Tags: rocket-league

What affects the path of the ball after an impact with a car? Certainly the angle of impact seems to be the biggest influence along with the velocity of the car relative to the ball. What about other factors?

Not limited to the following, but examples of things that could make a difference:

- Dodging, aside from how it changes speed? Does a 60kph impact in the
  same location on the ball at the same angle differ when dodging or
  not?
- Part of the car that makes impact?
- Spin of the car? Spin of the ball?
- Rocket boost vs not boosting, assuming same velocity? Stage 2 of boost? Hitting at the moment stage 2 of boost kicks in?
- Momentum of the ball? I feel like if a ball is traveling laterally
  across the field and I hit it up field, it tends to curve slightly
  back towards the direction of it's previous travel.

What factors change how a ball travels after being hit?

Answer (score 2):

The game uses quite a realistic physics engine. The ball is modelled as a sphere (roughly) and each car has a cuboid hitbox of slightly different dimensions. Therefore things like the tilt in a dodge or an aerial (using air roll) alters the trajectory of the ball after impact. Spin does affect the ball when travelling through the air as it curves towards the direction of spin but not when travelling along the ground (at least not noticeably). Obviously the angle at which you hit the ball is going to have the most effect on its trajectory. Collisions in the game are purely Newtonian and momentum based so boosting and driving at the same speed will have the same effect on the ball.

On a gameplay level, its best just to go in to free play and get use to the mechanics of the game instinctively so that you can judge what your touches will do to the ball.

Comment: `Spin does affect the ball when travelling through the air as it curves towards the direction of spin but not when travelling along the ground` - the general consensus is that you've just said the opposite of the truth. The ball does not curve in the air due to spin, spin only changes the direction of the ball when the ball bounces on the ground.